# Why is the matrix representation in the same basis not same for a density operator?

Tags: quantum-information, linear-algebra, density, eigenvalue

I have a $\rho : V \to V$ density operator of a $n$ dimensional space $V$ and $\{i\}=\{i_1,i_2..i_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis of this space. The density operator is defined as
$$\rho=\sum \lambda_{i}|i\rangle\langle i|.....(1)$$ 
Naturally matrix representation of $\rho$ in basis $\{i\}$ is
$$A=\text{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2...\lambda_n).....(2)$$
Now let $U$ be a unitary operator such that $U : V \to V^{'}$, where $V^{'}$ is also a $n$ dimensional space with an orthonormal basis $\{j\}=\{j_1,j_2...j_n\}$ such that
$$U|i\rangle = |j\rangle.....(3)$$
Thus if we apply $U$ on $\rho$ we get 
$$\rho^{'}=U\rho U^{\dagger}=\sum \lambda_j|j\rangle \langle j|....(4)$$
My doubt is if I write matrix representation of $\rho^{'}$ in basis $\{j\}$ I get
$$B=\text{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2...\lambda_n).....(5)$$
But I can also write representation of $\rho^{'}$ as
$$C=[U] A [U^{\dagger}].....(6)$$
Here $[U]$ means matrix representation of $U$ in input basis $\{i\}$ and output basis $\{j\}$.
Now as  both $C$ and $B$ are representations of $\rho^{'}$ in same basis $\{j\}$ they have to be the same thus $B=C$. But how can that be as $B$ is a diagonal matrix but $C$ is similar to the same diagonal matrix. I thought a lot it seems some basic mistake 
in understanding the concepts of basis but can't resolve what exactly the problem is.

Comment: Hint: you are just doing permutations of the same basis, but you have to keep better track of the transformation (permutation) of coefficients $\lambda$...

Comment: @yuggib I am mapping one orthogonal basis to another , how is it permuting I did not understand your point, could you please elaborate ?

Comment: the eigenvalues of a matrix do not change under unitary transformation; in addition you are ***supposing*** that your transformation of a diagonal matrix gives again a diagonal one; therefore you are just permuting the eigenvectors/corresponding eigenvalues (that are therefore not in the same order).

Comment: @yuggib I get your first point about eigenvalues being same. But I am unable to understand the fact that I am "supposing" matrices are diagonal I am just writing them in eigen basis. In what case won't they be diagonal ? I am really sorry I know I am bothering about trivial things but I can't understand. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: In equation (3) you are supposing that $Ui=j$, with both $\{i\}$ and $\{j\}$ orthonormal bases. This is possible only if, roughly speaking, you are doing a permutation of the same basis (at least in finite dimensions). In other words, you are identifying each eigenvector $i$ of $\rho$ with an eigenvector $j$ of $\rho'$, but since $\rho$ and $\rho'$ have the same spectrum and are diagonal, the identification is just a reshuffling of the order in which each row is written (a permutation).